# How does same origin policy solve issues with XHR, cookies and cross page commuication?

Tags: javascript, security, same-origin-policy

I understand that same origin policy is about restricting javascript from other domains from accessing contents of a page.

I read these particular points of importance of same origin policy on the Web:

- XmlHttpRequests: they don't work if done cross domain. But why would a Web page make an xhr request to a less trusted site in the first place? Isn't it the Web page's fault? Why impose a restriction then?
- cookies: it is not right if a malicious page can view my Facebook cookies. So if it tries to check "document.cookies" it will never see my Facebook cookies anyway. Where does same policy come into the picture here?
- cross page communication: the only way a malicious page opened in a tab can view information about another page is via cookies and or local storage. So where does same origin policy help here?

Comment: To make your life a lil difficult and easy at the same time :)

Comment: "the only way a malicious page opened in a tab can view information about another page is via cookies and or local storage" not true, without the same origin policy you could scrape iframes

Comment: I'd say it is time to pick up a few books on software security to learn why you need it in the first place, which in turn can open up the brain to love that your life is made difficult. Its not a good place to be when you attack it from the perspective of questioning its need.

Comment: Why is the question too broad? I've asked very specific questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> XmlHttpRequests

For example: To stop **your site** using **my browser** to get **my data** from **my bank's** website when my browser is logged into my bank.

> cookies

The same origin policy doesn't apply to cookies. Cookies are simply sent to the site for which they are registered.

> cross page communication: the only way a malicious page opened in a tab can view information about another page is via cookies and or local storage. So where does same origin policy help here?

You're operating under a misconception. Access to other pages is also available through `window.open` and frames (including iframes).

Once you have access to the DOM of another page, you can get data from it and you have the same issues that you would if XHR exposed other websites to JavaScript. Thus the same origin policy locks access to remote documents through frames.

Comment: `To stop your site using my browser to get my data from my bank's website when my browser is logged into my bank.` So without same origin policy how would my site accomplish this? Make an XHR request to your bank? that is the only other server in the situation. why would it give away your information?

Comment: "Make an XHR request to your bank?" — Yes. "why would it give away your information?" — Because I'm logged in and the request is coming from my browser.

Comment: `You're operating under a misconception. Access to other pages is also available through window.open and frames (including iframes).` But if I open a page with `window.open` or via an `iframe`, what is the harm in me seeing the whole DOM of the opened page? I opened it after all.

Comment: @learner — You didn't open it. You instructed my browser to open it. It might be my bank's website (and I am logged in). It might be my company intranet (and I'm behind a firewall).

Answer (score 2):

It's not about protecting you from accessing untrusted things, it's about preventing your page from accessing things it shouldn't. Without the same origin policy, there's nothing stopping you (with the user's cookies) from doing, say:

```
$.getJson('http://api.example.com/my/secret/stuff')
```

or

```
$('<iframe src="http://gmail.com">').appendTo('body').contents().html()
```

As for cookies, it's not really the Same Origin Policy in play here:

> Cookies use a separate definition of origins. A page can set a cookie for its own domain or any parent domain, as long as the parent domain is not a public suffix.

(from [Same-origin policy at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_data_storage_access))

Answer (score -1):

If I use a XSS flaw to put a remote, evil js on your page, it cannot make requests to your, or any random, server. (actually, it can, but it doesn't have all features on)

Comment: If I were to use an XSS flaw to put remote, evil JS on your page, then it would have complete access to your server. The same origin policy doesn't protect against XSS at all. XSS is a different class of security problem.